# DNN Wrong Password Reset link

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I have problems when I force reset passwords for my website users.

When I use this option, the next time the user logs in it will be prompted to change the password. My website link is something like this: Server/MyPortal.

When users login instead of taking them to:

Server/**MyPortal**/default.aspx?ctl=PasswordReset&resetToken...

They are redirected to:

Server/default.aspx?ctl=PasswordReset&resetToken...

Which obviously takes them to a 404 not found page because it is missing **MyPortal**.

Can anyone please shed some light on me and help me to fix this? Thank you very much!

Ivan

Answer (score 0):

What version of DNN are you on?

I would look at

1. Are you on the latest version
2. Are your Portal Aliases configured properly. To tell this, login as a Super User, go to the Admin/Site Settings page for the portal in question, find the Portal Aliases section, I believe that is under the Advanced tab. See if you have a misconfigured alias in there.

Another thing you might check, would be to check the Language files (admin/languages) to see if the password reset email could be modified there to include the proper portal URL. When editing language files in DNN you can edit System, Host, or Site.

You likely want to edit the SITE level if you have other websites running as well. Site level edits will only apply to that individual portal.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. The portal version is 07.04.00. So yes, I'm at the latest version. All aliases are correct. They are serverip/MyPortal and localhost/MyPortal. I tried the language files but it takes users to the same broken link. The last comment about the SITE level, couldn't figure out where to check that out.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in this release. I tried version 7.03.03 and it works but it shows me the button to send the reset password link by email. But that does not work for me because I don't intend to add the SMTP service for email notifications. Any idea how to set it up so users can reset the password right there instead of receiving the email link?